# Android fetch latitude and longitude initially with Network provider and later with GPS

Tags: android, gps, location

In my app i need latitude and longitude values of the current position of the user. Initially i check whether GPS co ordinates are available or not and if not available i will fetch these lat lon values of the user's position using Network provider as fetching GPS co ordinates is time consuming. Once the GPS co ordiantes are available i need to obtain these values. Googling for about 2 days i found some info about the issue and managed to build some code as shown below. I am stuck and unable to go forward.

My activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    double x, y;

    Timer timer;
    LocationManager lm;
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        network_enabled = lm
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "nothing is enabled",
                    duration);
            toast.show();

        }

        if (gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListenerGps);
        if (network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListenerNetwork);
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);

    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer.cancel();
            x = location.getLatitude();
            y = location.getLongitude();
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                    "gps enabled " + x + "\n" + y, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer.cancel();
            x = location.getLatitude();
            y = location.getLongitude();
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "network enabled" + x + "\n"
                    + y, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
            if (gps_enabled)
                gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (network_enabled)
                net_loc = lm
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            // if there are both values use the latest one
            if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {
                if (gps_loc.getTime() > net_loc.getTime()) {
                    x = gps_loc.getLatitude();
                    y = gps_loc.getLongitude();
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "gps lastknown " + x
                            + "\n" + y, duration);
                    toast.show();
                } else {
                    x = net_loc.getLatitude();
                    y = net_loc.getLongitude();
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "network lastknown "
                            + x + "\n" + y, duration);
                    toast.show();

                }

            }

            if (gps_loc != null) {
                {
                    x = gps_loc.getLatitude();
                    y = gps_loc.getLongitude();
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "gps lastknown " + x
                            + "\n" + y, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }

            }
            if (net_loc != null) {
                {
                    x = net_loc.getLatitude();
                    y = net_loc.getLongitude();
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "network lastknown "
                            + x + "\n" + y, duration);
                    toast.show();

                }
            }
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "no last know avilable",
                    duration);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
}
```

So far using the above code i am getting lat lon values from network provider but unable to get GPS co ordinates. What should i add or edit to the above code to fetch GPS co ordinates?

Answer (score 1):

I found the Android developer's guide very helpful: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate

It illustrates how a typical program flow should look like in order to obtain the most accurate user's position using different location providers.

Comment: i already went thru the developer guide. But i got lost working with it. not able to make things work.

Comment: Well, the first thing I notice is that you should not work with timers. Let the LocationManager inform you about location updates. The. idea is also not complicated. Whenever you obtain a new location, we need to have a logic that decides whether this is a 'better' location as the one before. The guide I cited shows an example how to do this.

Comment: thanks for that. Do u have any sample code to show me how can i proceed further?

Comment: I would simply call the method I cited above in the `onLocationChanged` listener.